# What is the point of this strange "answer" (just bunch of words)?

Tags: discussion

There is strange ["answer"](https://superuser.com/a/702289/238539) on the question. It obviously does not make any sense. English is not my first language but I can see that there is no any sense or idea which author attempting to communicate. It appears to be a bunch of words. There are no any links in the message which can give author some profit by advertising something. It is not offensive. It just does not make any sense. So what is this and why should someone post this? What is profit?

Per user's [profile](https://superuser.com/users/290408/marcusjones) this is only message he posted. By the way, his profile does not have any links as well.

Only one sane explanation I could think with is - [Numbers station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_station).

Do you have any ideas about this post?

Post was flagged and thus soon will be removed, so I will provide it here for reference

[image: spam post]

**EDIT**

So, I liked idea given by Sathya:

> The person is copy+pasting the content. Since textbox is plaintext not
>   richtext/html text, all formatting, including links were lost and the
>   person didn't bother to verify..

And I did test it by copy-pasting same content with links from different resource into the textbox which we use when answer and create questions. Indeed all URL did not survive and became plain text, but phrases of this URL did not disappear. (I removed titles of stuff they advertising and put dots instead.)

---

[image: spam textbox test]

---

Anyway, I think we are done with this discussion, I am happy with what I have found - this is just spam and somehow URL links and text got cut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automated spam link removal. This is my thought of thinking:

- users with <10 rep can't link more than 2 URLs
- Since the person couldn't link, I presume the person just pasted the wall of text, with the intention to add link later

or

- The person is copy+pasting the content. Since textbox is plaintext not richtext/html text, all formatting, including links were lost and the person didn't bother to verify..

Comment: I see. Look at comment which I left for slhck under my own answer. So there is some sort of spam recognition since system notified me.

Comment: `Since textbox is plaintext not richtext/html text`, make sense, but in this case should the links appear as plaintext? They are completely missing in our case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found answer. I searched online part of this text and a lot of results were found. I visited one result and found same text but with links to different resources. So it is spam. I guess Super User's engine recognizes common spam techniques and cuts out any links which are known to be spam. Well done.

Comment: There's no automatic link removal I'm afraid. Also, if the system had determined the post was spam, why let it through?

Comment: @slhck, I got to this post by reviewing answers from new users. I was going thru and when this one appeared - there was small notification area on top of it saying something like `Our system determined this post as possible spam. Please review it more carefully`. After 2 seconds notification disappeared.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty new – but I just had a developer confirm that there is no automatic removal of links from posts determined as possible spam.